# How to clear vim registers effectively?

Tags: vim, vim-registers

Registers in vim are a great feature to store text snippets and even to run commands on the text stored within them. However, I'm a tidy person and tend to clean things up when I'm done.

I know that if I wanted to clear register `a`, I can use <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

I can also execute the following command:

```
:let @a = ''
```

However, these solutions seem like a mere workaround to the problem. When I execute `:registers`, the list still displays register `a` (with an empty value), while registers that have otherwise never been used are not displayed.

Is there a way to clear a register with the side-effect of removing the register from this list?

And if so, is there also a way to clear all registers at once, i.e., to reset that list of registers?

Comment: I guess I'm *not* a tidy person --- I never look under the `:reg`

Answer (score 47):

Since that venerable answer on the mailing list, linked by [@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431165/15934), we have `setreg('a', [])` that clears the register.

Thus, the code could become:

```
let regs=split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-"', '\zs')
for r in regs
  call setreg(r, [])
endfor
```

Comment: Wow - this actually removes it from the `:registers` list! Thanks!! ^u^

Comment: Not for me; `:exec setreg('a', [])` gives me `E730: using List as a String` and doesn't remove nor empty the register.

Comment: At some point in time, vim has started to reject `:let a =1` + `:let a = {}`. During last year, this was reverted. I suspect you have a vim version compiled at some point in between those two patches.

Comment: What does this do with the Capitalised letters? (`ABC...`). My understanding is that there is no `A` register - instead using `A` appends to the `a` register.

Comment: @dgmstuart, your understanding is correct. As a consequence, it seems that appending an empty list to a register leaves it unmodified.

Comment: @LukeDavis, with `setreg('a', '')`, the register _a_ still appears in `:registers`. With `setreg('a', [])`, it is removed, which answers OP's question.

Comment: This is exactly what I want and this is the best answer to the question.We should vote it up.

Comment: Hi there, just tested `:exe setreg('a', [])` and for `vim` this does indeed erase the register `a` completely, but in `nvim`, it replaces its content with `^J` (equivalent of `<Esc>`) instead. Can someone reproduce this ? If so, how to achieve the wanted behavior of deleting the register in neovim ?

Comment: @Atralb Note: it's not `:execute`, it's `:call`. With `exe`, you try to execute the result of `setreg()` which should be 0 (a function with no value returned will return 0 in vim script), This means that this will execute `:0`, IOW, it'll move the cursor to the first line. Regarding nvim, I have no idea. Try to see what `:h setreg()` returns in case there is some specific parameter combinations with nvim. May be you should try to ask on nvim mailing list -- I guess there is one.

Answer (score 24):

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
command! WipeReg for i in range(34,122) | silent! call setreg(nr2char(i), []) | endfor
```

and clear every register with `:WipeReg`

If you would like that to happen every time you start Vim also add:

```
autocmd VimEnter * WipeReg
```

Comment: To avoid the confusion I went through, after clearing the registers (`:W` is an alias) you then need to write to viminfo with `:wv!` on vim and shada on nvim with `:wsh!` to make it persistent.

Answer (score 19):

AFAIK you can't use built-in commands/functions to make registers disappear from the list. That seems to be doable only by removing them from your `~/.viminfo` which sounds a bit extreme.

[this thread on the vim mailing list](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-clear-registers-td1143529.html) has a command that clears every register but it doesn't remove them from `:reg`:

```
let regs='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-"' | let i=0 | while (i<strlen(regs)) | exec 'let @'.regs[i].'=""' | let i=i+1 | endwhile | unlet regs
```

--- EDIT ---

The command above is no longer needed but here is a breakdown for the curious:

```
" The value of variable regs is a string made up of all named
" and numbered registers, plus the search, small delete, and
" unnamed registers. A string can be used as a list for our
" use case so we use the most concise method. We could have
" done let regs = ['a', 'b', 'c', etc. instead.
let regs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-"'

" We are going to iterate through the string so we initialize
" a loop counter with value 0.
let i = 0

" Here is our loop where we check at each iteration if the loop
" counter is smaller than the length of regs.
while (i < strlen(regs))

    " If it is, we programmatically assign an empty string
    " to each corresponding register
    exec 'let @' . regs[i] . ' = ""'

    " and we add 1 to the loop counter.
    let i = i + 1
endwhile

" Once we are done, we get rid of the variable we created above
" which is now unnecessary.
unlet regs
```

Comment: Hmm. That same strategy does work to clear the search register. `:map <silent> <F2> :let @/ = ""` Shame it doesn't work for what the OP wants.

Comment: Hi romainl and jpaugh, in both of your comments, you instructed to override the content of every register with the content from the unnamed register "".  But what confuses me is why the current unnamed register is supposed to be empty?  We should first clear the unnamed register at least and then assign "the blank" to every registers, isn't it? But sadly, somehow your instructions work fine.  I have no knowledge to the VimL.

Comment: @leoleohu, no. The command assigns an empty string to each register,  not the content of the unnamed register. I can see where the confusion might come from so I will add some explanation to my answer. Note that Luc Hermitte's answer is now the correct one so you should probably not pay to much attention to this one.

Comment: @romainl, your update explains.  I now understand "" represents a empty string, not the unnamed register.  This misunderstanding comes from my missing knowledge in VimL.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

Remove `.viminfo` file or delete the register line in the `.viminfo` file.

You can get the details from [Here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#viminfo-file):

```
The viminfo file is used to store:
- The command line history.
- The search string history.
- The input-line history.
- Contents of non-empty registers.
- Marks for several files.
- File marks, pointing to locations in files.
- Last search/substitute pattern (for 'n' and '&').
- The buffer list.
- Global variables
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to never load any registers. As others have said, registers are loaded from `.viminfo`. The `-i` flag is used to specify what viminfo file to use. If you specify `NONE`, no viminfo, and therefore no registers will be loaded.

```
vim -i NONE
```

Comment: This is good but of course you lose the benefit of the .viminfo files full stop for this. That's unfortunate. Still a valid way to go about it.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, I'll note that while setting a register to contain an empty string doesn't remove the register from the output of the `:registers` command, Vim does not save registers which have been cleared in this way to the `.viminfo` file.

Therefore, one other quick-and-dirty alternative for removing specific registers from the list is to clear them using either of the commands you suggest, and then restart Vim.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to set a value for each used register, similar to romainl's approach:

```
function! ClearRegisters()
   redir => l:register_out
   silent register
   redir end
   let l:register_list = split(l:register_out, '\n')
   call remove(l:register_list, 0) " remove header (-- Registers --)
   call map(l:register_list, "substitute(v:val, '^.\\(.\\).*', '\\1', '')")
   call filter(l:register_list, 'v:val !~ "[%#=.:]"') " skip readonly registers
   for elem in l:register_list
      execute 'let @'.elem.'= ""'
   endfor
endfunction
```

This avoids including additional register on the output of `:registers`